# Is this XDocument code safe?

Tags: c#, xml, web-services

I'm writing a class called **Category** which has 2 static methods for retreiving XML data from an external resource. In my example below I'm only going to show one because they're very similar.

What I'm trying to find out is whether this code is "Safe" in terms of invalid URLs, invalid data etc.. basically make it more robust. **Here's teh codes**

```
private static string XmlUri
    {
        get { return "path-to-xml-file"; }
    }
private static XDocument XmlFile { get; set; }
public int ID { get; set; }
public string Name { get; set; }
public int Parent { get; set; }

/// <summary>
/// Gets a specific category
/// </summary>
/// <param name="id"></param>
/// <returns>A Category with the specified ID</returns>
public static Category Get(int id)
{
    try
    {
        if (XmlFile == null)
            XmlFile = XDocument.Load(XmlUri);
    }
    // Invalid URL or data
    catch (Exception ex)
    {

        // TODO: Log exception
        Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
    }

    if (XmlFile == null)
        return null;

    var cat = from category in XmlFile.Descendants("Category")
               where category.Attribute("id").Value.ParseSafe() == id
               select new Category
               {
                   ID = category.Attribute("id").Value.ParseSafe(),
                   Parent = category.Attribute("parent").Value.ParseSafe(),
                   Name = category.Value
               };

    return cat.SingleOrDefault();
}
```

Comment: How much control do you have with the external XML? You may want to validate it against a schema. Also your code may explode *(To use technical terms...)* when multiple threads try to read XML.

Comment: @Chaos - I've got NO control over the XML file what-so-ever so I have to work with what I've got. Could you please explain the thread-safety part a little bit more, it doesn't sound like I'll ever run into that scenario but want to be sure. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Define 'safe'. Your code will produce `null` when something is wrong. I would consider a (re-)throw in the catch block after XDocument.Load(). To be safe in **not** ignoring an invalid URL.

And that puts the ParseSafe() and SingleOrDefault into question as well. What do you want to happen if an `id` is missing or malformed?

And, a small improvement: You could put the Load-on-Demand logic into the getter of XmlFile. Makes it easier if you also want other elements beside Category.

Comment: +1: for "return null" behafior. May not be expected by callers.

Comment: Thanks @Henk, I'm returning null in case of any errors and the other part of the application which will be using this class will be checking for null before doing any other work. The ParseSafe method is simply a string extension that returns an integer using int.TryParse and returns 0 if is invalid. I presume SingleOrDefault will return null as well if there's no matches found which I am actually aiming for. As for the load-on-demand logic, did you mean something like this? `private static XDocument XmlFile{ get { return XDocument.Load(XmlUri);} }`

Comment: If your caller does not care about the difference between "no results" and "provider explode" it is OK. And I meant an `if x != null` inside the getter.

Answer (score 1):

Not thread safe as ChaosPandion mentioned.

Confusing performance behavior - Get(int) looks like simple fast method, but actually involves non-trivial work. Use lazy initialization and read whole collection of categories onece into dictionary.

Should not catch Exception and swallow it - either use specific ones (I think IOException and XMLExcepetion in this case) or at least let fatal exceptions to be thrown normally.

Obviously if you don't contol XML file it can also cause slownes/hangs while loading insanely large files. Depending on behavior of reader and complexity of XML (if given to you by malicious party) could cause some other exceptions like StackOverflow killing your process.

Comment: Hey @Alexei sorry for my late response I've just come out of a meeting. I actually **don't** have any control over the XML file unfortunately. Can you explain a bit more about the thread safety part, the idea was that I only load the XML file once and store it in memory to be used multiple times... The application is a console app which will be scheduled to run at a certain time and populate a database so there will just be one foreach loop iterating through the nodes and adding them to the database, will that cause any issues with thread safety?

Comment: If you console application does not involve creation of threads or other explcit asynchronous processing (i.e. QueueUserWorkItem) you don't need to worry about thread safety of the code. If you methods are called from multiple threads you need to worry about synchronization between threads while accessing non-immutable structures (i.e. there is no guarantees for XDocument methods to be safe for access from multiple threads at the same time, while Dictionary allows such access if no modifications are made). Search for "writing thread safe code" to find information...

Comment: "I don't control XML" - it's more of a question if you expect malicious XML or just invalid. Later is easier to handle and your code is fine for non-public tool running in friendly environment.